# Host function on firestore for an android app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to developp an android app which will use a firestore's database. The user can click on a button to collect data from all user's. I noticed it took a while to do (the app check the database, then for each user which are documents read their values, do a calcul based on the time since they have created their account, then add all of that into a number).

I was wondering if there would be a more optimised way to do this ? Like is this possible to have, like a function or I don't know how to call it, on the firestore server that would do this calcul like each minute or hour, then the app only query the result store in a int on the database ?

I'm a newbie in this field so I might not be using the right terms for things.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing calculations by reading a bunch of data on each client is typically an anti-pattern when using NoSQL database like Firestore. They're best if you have a fairly direct mapping from the data in the database to what you show in the screens of your app.

Firestore has no built-in server-side calculations on its own. You'll typically want to perform those in something like Cloud Functions, which can either run in response to writing to Firestore (and other Firebase and Google Cloud products), or [run periodically on a schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

Comment: Hi Frank,

Thanks for your answer ! So I don't know if it's good or bad news for me ^^" as it was feeling wrong and slow what I was doing, so cloud functions seems to be a good solution.

Then I tried to search for tutorials (I'm barely beginning with android studio/firebase) and only found incomprehensible videos using virtual studio with barely no explications :/ If you have good ressources on the topic I'm interested. Then I noticed a major drawback : I went to see on firebase console about cloud functions, turns out you have to pay to even try it :/ So I can't even test that for free..

Comment: To be more precise on my pricing concern, since I would like to have a function that run every minute for all clients, I guess it's not enough to be charged for if I understood their pricing ? However, it's indicated that in the new "blaze plan" each authentification have to be pay, so that means that I would have to pay while learning how to code as my app is using auth and I'm learning by iteration ? :/

Comment: **On pricing**: Cloud Functions have a free tier, but you need to be on the paid plan to use them. Authentication for most providers is free, only phone authentication is charged - and even that has a free tier too. **On tutorials**: recommending off-site resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but I usually learn from Firebase's own docs, codelabs and tutorials, or from someone like fireship.io.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I've accepted your answer I think this close the topic ? Just a quick question, if I go with the blaze plan and the cloud function does not fit my need, could I go back to the free plan ? Thanks again

Comment: You can change the plan of your project at any time. Also see: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#pricing-modify-plan (and I recommend checking that page frequently, as it cover most common questions)